# Приведение REG_BINARY к FILETIME

Tags: windows, реестр, tcl

Есть ключ реестра `HKLM\SYSTEM\DriberDatabase`, в нем значение `UpdateDate` типа `REG_BINARY`, являющееся полями структуры `FILETIME`. Значение извлекаю так:

```
package require registry
set path {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase}
set fields [registry get $path "updatedate"]
```

Однако в `$fields` оказывается какое-то безобразие вместо вменяемых данных. Нужно полагать, что для получения адекватного результата нужно сделать ряд дополнительных действий. Прошу подсказать каких именно.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `binary scan`.

```
if {$tcl_platform(os) ne "Windows NT"} {
  throw {OSERROR} {"Сценарий может быть запущен только в Windows."}
}

package require registry

set key   {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase}
set epoch 116444736000000000 ; # эпоха как FILETIME
set nano  10000000           ; # сто наносекунд

# если в текущей версии системы данный ключ реестра не найден
if {[catch {binary scan [registry get $key "updatedate"] i* ft} e]} {
  puts stderr [concat "\[Ошибка\]: " [lindex [split $e :] 0]]
  exit 1
}

# переменная $ft содержит значения полей FILETIME
set sec [expr (([lindex $ft 1] << 32 | [lindex $ft 0]) - $epoch) / $nano]
puts [clock format $sec -format {%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S}]
```